# Split on non arabic characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like this

```
أصبح::ينال::أخذ::حصل (على)::أحضر
```

And I want to split it on non Arabic characters using java

And here's my code

```
String s = "أصبح::ينال::أخذ::حصل (على)::أحضر";
String[] arr = s.split("^\\p{InArabic}+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

And the output was

```
[, ::ينال::أخذ::حصل (على)::أحضر]
```

But I expect the output to be

```
[ينال,أخذ,حصل,على,أحضر]
```

So I don't know what's wrong with this?

Comment: can not you replace all :: with ""?

Comment: You need to split on `[^\\p{InArabic}]+` - you forgot the character class. Outside of `[]`, `^` is a line start anchor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need a negated class, and to do that, you need square brackets `[ ... ]`. Try to split with this:

```
"[^\\p{InArabic}]+"
```

If `\\p{InArabic}` matches any arabic character, then `[^\\p{InArabic}]` will match any non-arabic character.

---

Another option you can consider is an equivalent syntax, using `P` instead of `p` to indicate the opposite of the `\\p{InArabic}` character class like @Pshemo mentioned:

```
"\\P{InArabic}+"
```

This works just like `\\W` is the opposite of `\\w`.

The only possible advantage you get with the first syntax over the second (again like @Pshemo mentioned), is that if you want to add other characters to the list of characters which shouldn't match, for example, if you want to match all non `\\p{InArabic}` except periods, the first one is more flexible:

```
"[^\\p{InArabic}.]+"
                ^
```

Otherwise, if you really want to use `\\P{InArabic}`, you'll need [subtraction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) within classes:

```
"[\\P{InArabic}&&[^.]]+"
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't think so - it's a _negated_ character class.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Indeed. I missed the `^`.

Comment: If I am not mistaken `\P{xxx}` is negation of `\p{xxx}` so no `[^\p{xxx}]` is needed (unless you want to add more `\p{xyz}` classes to `[...]`).

Answer (score 16):

The expression you want is `"\\P{InArabic}+"`

This means match any (non-zero) number of characters that are not Arabic.